# Selenium: setHeadless() has no effect for ChromeDriver

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to use Chrome in [headless mode](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome) for Selenium tests. Here is what I do:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    RemoteWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(new ChromeOptions().setHeadless(true));
    try {
        driver.navigate().to("https://example.com/");
        File file = driver.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        Files.copy(file.toPath(), Paths.get("target/screenshot.png"), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

        // adding a delay to visually check whether there is a browser window
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } finally {
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

I'm using `setHeadless(true)` on `ChromeOptions` instance, but when I run this, Chrome window pops up. It seems like Chrome ignores that headless setting.

**The question is**: why does Chrome ignore the setting and how to make it respect it?

I have Chrome 63.0.3239.108, an official 64-bit build, under Ubuntu Linux 16.04. Selenium is of version 3.8.1.

Here is my `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.rpuch.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-selenium-headless-chrome</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

The project is available at Github: https://github.com/rpuch/test-selenium-headless-chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that chromedriver that was installed in my system was a bit outdated: it had version 2.30. Probably it does not support 'headless' feature (which is pretty recent in Chrome itself).

With the most recent version of [chromedriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) (2.34) everything works as expected: I don't see any browser window, but the screenshot is created successfully.

Answer (score 0):

The headless feature in chrome is implemented in version 59 onwards as per [google](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome). and ChromeDriver v2.30 should support this, But as per the above reference,

> ChromeDriver 2.32 uses Chrome 61 and works well with headless Chrome.